# why am i getting and interger in this case when am dividing a odd integer with 2?

Tags: python, list, oop

```
class Solution(object):
    def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1, nums2):
        """
        :type nums1: List[int]
        :type nums2: List[int]
        :rtype: float
        """
        nums3 = nums1+nums2
        nums3.sort()
        
        if len(nums3)%2!=0:
            med = nums3[len(nums3)//2]
            return med 
        else:
            print(nums3)
            med = ((nums3[len(nums3)//2]+nums3[(len(nums3)//2)-1])/2) #my problem
            return med
```

In the test case nums1 = [1,2] and nums2 = [3,4], I am supposed to get 2.5 as an answer but instead of that am getting 2.

This question is called Median of Two sorted arrays.

Comment: When I run this code, I get 2.5.  Can you show us exactly how you run this code, and how you are printing the result.

Comment: ahh my bad man i was using python 2.

Comment: Are you still using Python 2.x, for some bizarre reason?  If so, you'd need to write the division as `/2.0` to get it to be performed with floating-point math.

Comment: I get 2.5 too. That being said, pls use a variable for `len(nums3) // 2`. Also aim for a linear solution, the plain sorting of nums3 does not make proper use of the sorted arrays (merge!).

Comment: @user2390182 Can you plz elaborate plain sorting of num3? And are you telling to use merge sort?

Comment: I'd say it's premature optimization. Most sort algorithms have O(n log n). I think your code is fine.

Comment: @HarshitSingh For the fun of it, I posted an answer with linear time and constant space complexity.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Python doesn't use most sort algorithms, though :-). It's O(m+n) here. But the solution is supposed to be O(log (m+n)), so O(m+n) isn't fine.